# React-Bootstrap Table with dynamic Content - Form over Radio Buttons in Rows not working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

In my React App I request data from an API and store it in state:

```
const [entities, setEntities] = useState([]);
```

in my `useEffect` hook I get the Data from the API - basicly I have the following example array as my entities:

```
 ["@Organization", "@City", "@Immobilie", "@Currency", "@Test"]
```

Now I want to display all entities in a table and have a radio button in each row to select ONE entity.
I'm using [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) to build the Table

```
<Table striped bordered style={{ color: "#4d4d4d" }}>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Entities</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>                                        
                                    {entities.map(entity => <tr key={entity} style={{ color: "#4d4d4d" }}>
                                        <td>
                                            <Row>
                                                <Col>
                                                <Form.Check 
                                                    type="radio"
                                                    label={entity}/>                                                        
                                                </Col>
                                            </Row>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>)}
                                </tbody>
                            </Table>
```

In the `<tbody>` I map every entry of the `entities` array to a Table Element.
But Now I can click the Radio Button in each tablerow, without deselecting the others.
I tried to wrap a `<Form>` element around the Table, but nothing changes.
If I wrap the `<Form>` around the `<tbody>` the `<tbody>` doesnt get populated with tablerows.
When I put the `<Form>` inside the `<Table>` element the whole table doesn't render anymore.

How can I group the radio Buttons so only one is selectable in this dynamicly build table?

Comment: Have you given the same name for each `Form.Check` element?

Comment: @TheKNVB I added a name attribute now it's working thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [The KNVB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2018278/the-knvb)s comment I added a name attribute to my `Form.Check` element

```
<Form.Check 
  type="radio"
  name="entitySelection"                                                        
  label={entity} />
```

Now only one tablerow-radio Button is selectable